# Search Intersections with ArcGIS Server 10 without using Address Locator

Tags: arcgis-server, intersection

Is there a way to search for intersections on a centerline layer in ArcGIS Server 10 without using an Address Locator?

I can send direct queries to the centerline layer for individual road segments.  For example, if I add query?text=Main to the layer URL in a browser window, it will return all roads where the display field matches "Main".

Is there a similar query I can do to find intersections?  I know this is possible with an Address Locator, but I am trying to find an alternative.

Thanks,
Seth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're wanting to use the REST API, [this URL](http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Locators/ESRI_Geocode_USA/GeocodeServer/findAddressCandidates?Address=State+st%40new+york&City=&State=&Zip=92373&outFields=&f=pjson) (for State St@New York, zipcode 92373) works.

```
http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Locators/ESRI_Geocode_USA/GeocodeServer/findAddressCandidates?Address=State+st%40new+york&City=&State=&Zip=92373&outFields=&f=pjson
```

If ESRI is eating their own dogfood, they [used a locator when they published the geocoding service](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_dotnet_help/index.html#//009300000025000000.htm).

If you don't want to use their REST API, I guess you could write a [Server Object Extension](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_cpp/componenthelp/index.html#//0019000000qm000000) that queries the featureclass for either street name, then loops through each feature to find the point(s) that are common to the two different streets.

Comment: Thanks Kirk, do you know of any examples online that are similar to that?